# Laravel, query on joined table after join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**The functionality:**
I'm displaying a list of responses (user is related to a response), and i want to be able  filter by user name

I have an assignment response table with a user id in it

i am joining users to this table based on that id

i have a search filter for these responses

**I want to be able to search by user name**

Is it possible to do something like this;

```
$responses = AssignmentResponse::query()->where('assignment_id', '=', $request->assignment)
        ->with([
            'likes',
            'user'
        ]);

    //FILTERS
    if ($request->queryString) {
        $responses->where('user.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->queryString . '%');
    }

    return $responses->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply alter the relationship with a callback:

```php
return AssignmentResponse::where('assignment_id', $request->assignment)
    ->with('likes')
    ->when(
        $request->filled("queryString"),
        function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereHas("user", fn ($q) => $q->where("name", "like", "%$request->queryString%"))
                ->with(["user" => fn ($q) => $q->where("name", "like", "%$request->queryString%")]);
        }
    )
    ->get()
```

Note both [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) and [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) are used to ensure only matching values are returned. A [conditional clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) is used in place of your `if` statement.